# Backup of rsync tree

Tags: ssh, rsync, rsnapshot

I have a production server A and a VM server B (test and dev). Server B has hourly rsnapshots of server A. We'd like to use the snapshot tree at server B for further propragation to one of our branch offices.

Is this adviseable or possible?

Edit: "rsync snapshots" => rsnapshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely possible, I've done it myself in the past, just keep in mind that you're making a copy of a copy so it'll always be 2 "generations" behind (and by generations I mean 2 copies behind).

Also if the sync between A and B breaks your copy in C will also be broken, so C will only be as good as B is.

If you're doing this just for redundancy sake and it's not your backup system go ahead, if on the other hand you want this as backup, I would rather sync directly to A.